# How to get the item position on a clickListener set in an Adapter class?

Tags: android, gridview, adapter, android-mediaplayer

I'm creating a very simple soundbox app.I'm using a GridView which contains items (representation of a sound). An item is composed with an ImageView and a TextView

I have a problem in my adapter. Here is the code :

```
public class SoundAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Sound>{

    private Sound[] items;
    private Context context = null;

    public SoundAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, Sound[] items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        SoundHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

            holder = new SoundHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.txtDescription = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.description);

            row.setTag(holder);

            //Here is the clickListener I want

        }else {
            holder = (SoundHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        Sound sound = items[position];

        if(sound != null){
            holder.txtDescription.setText(sound.getDescription());
            holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.muscle1);
        }

        return row;
    }

    static class SoundHolder
    {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtDescription;
    }
}
```

Currently I have a onItemClickListener on my gridView in my main which create a new MediaPlayer object associated with the clicked item. So the click event is for all the item (TextView + ImageView)

What I want to do is a clickListener only on the ImageView in the getView() method where I put the comment line:

```
    holder.imgIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //create the MediaPlayer object
                        //start the media player
                    }
});
```

But with this solution I can't access the position of the item inside the clickListener. So it is impossible for me to access the correct sound. (I need the position to get the sound and create the MediaPlayer object)

Do you have an idea about how to achieve something like that ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `But with this solution I can't access the position of the item` approach is right let me know what problem getting using current code?

Comment: Inside the clickListener I can't access the position parameter of the method getView(),, so I can't get the sound associated with this image (every sounds have the same image in the ImageView by default) and I can't create the MediaPlayer like that : `MediaPlayer.create(context, mSounds[position].getSoundResourceId());` because I can't do mSounds[position].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Inside the clickListener I can't access the position parameter of the
>   method getView()

Either declare `position` parameter of `getView` method as `final`  or use `getTag/setTag` method of `ImageView` for getting position inside onClick method.

Using `getTag/setTag` :

```
    if (row == null) { 
        // your code here...
        row.setTag(holder);
    }else {
        holder = (SoundHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    Sound sound = items[position];
    // add click listener here
    holder.imgIcon.setTag(String.valueOf(position));
```

and in onClick method get position from v:

```
@Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      int pos=Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
      //create the MediaPlayer object
      //start the media player
  }
```

Comment: Thank you ! It works perfectly ! I feel very stupid because I wasn't creating the clickListener at the correct place. I spent many hours trying to find the solution and now I have it it seems obvious. Thanks a lot. Just can you tell me what is the best solution : the position parameter in final or the tag solution ?

Comment: @Mtoypc: Both way is best

Comment: Ok I'll take the final method. Thanks